# Excel find string in string in range return data in corresponding column

Tags: excel

The Excel thingy again. ;-)

I have columns like this:

```
A         B             C
UserID    Name          Org_Name
1         Brian Green   Susan Red
2         Niels Red     Susan Blue
3         Susan Yellow  Brian Green
4         India Orange  Serge Black
```

I am looking for a formula that can find ORG_Name(C) in Name(B) and return the UserID(A) and Name(B) found.

In this case it could look like this:

```
A         B             C              D         E
UserID    Name          Org_Name       FoundID   FoundName
1         Brian Green   Susan Red      N/A       N/A
2         Niels Red     Susan Blue     N/A       N/A
3         Susan Yellow  Brian Green    1         Brian Green
4         India Orange  Serge Black    N/A       N/A
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula for FoundID column:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

Formula for FoundName column:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

Adjust the end row as required (the 5s in both formulas)

Comment: For the column `FoundName` you can also use a simpler formula: e.g. `=IF(D1="N/A";"";C1)`

Comment: =INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("*"&C3&"*";B:B;0))